# What does the phrase "punctuate proceedings" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the sentence:

> With this app, You can add audio effects, and you can also **punctuate proceedings** with the sound
>   of a flying aeroplane or an air horn.

The sentence is from a DJ app which lets its users access a great number of sound tools on their mobile.

I know the lexical meanings of both [punctuate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punctuate) and [proceedings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceedings), but I am not sure what do they mean when used together in this context. Is it about adding special sounds to signify intervals between events or does it simply mean adding some sounds which are played intermittently?

Comment: Raj used such an app on *the Big Bang Theory* ('?' = *Jeopardy* theme, etc.).  The common allusion to punctuation includes pauses (commas?), but I think the repertoire is more like interjections.  Punctuation is more like a multiplicative factor of the lexical words.

Answer (score 1):

The language used here may be slightly unusual in the context of a DJ app, but it seems that the intended meaning is that you can play these additional sounds whenever you want over the music to add to it - as the commenter above suggested, this is more like an interjection than punctuation.